# is there any alternate way for creating multiple activities and multiple recycler views to display different content in android app

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

[image: This is the Ui of my app now if a user clicks on a button(any dept) a list of contents will be displayed using recycler view].[image: now in this image if user clicks content will be displayed]

As of now when a user clicks on button cse ,cse activity starts which displays list of items using recyclerview,next csedescription activity is used to display its content.In same way if I do for
all other departments I have to create more activities ,is there any other alternative method to make it easier??

Answer (score 1):

Try to implement this UI with Jetpack Compose, you don't have to bother with activity/fragment/recyclerview...

[Jetpack Compose tutorial](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in fact you don't need Multiple Activitie - what you need is a Single Activity hosting multiple Fragments.

Instead of the Buttons you can use a RecyclerView to display a list of Departments and when a RecyclerView Item is pressed it Navigates you to the respective Fragment.

You can read about [Single Activity and Navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-migrate) here.

Comment: can u explain me  a bit further please

Comment: The link I have shared above should help you get started. Alternatively you can opt for Jetpack Compose but you will need to put more study time as this is a new Architecture which became stable inlate July